# Multiple Queries from multiple tables with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, join

I have 12 tables i want to query from the database based on the user search options.

This is a visual schema diagram of the table

[selected tables to query visual schema diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLU6u.jpg)

The is a UI of the select options the user will select to search the database.

[UI of query fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKm2i.jpg)

This is the controller i have tried but always have failures.

```
$center = Input::get("center");
    $course = Input::get("course");
    $parentInfo = Input::get("parent-info");
    $feedingList = Input::get("feeding-list");
    $kitCollectionList = Input::get("kit-colection-list");
    $paymentStatus = Input::get("payment-status");
    $verifiedPayment = Input::get("verified-payments");
    $attendanceList = Input::get("attendance-list");
    $laptopRentalList = Input::get("laptop-rental-list");
    $pinList = Input::get("pins-list");
    $siblings = Input::get("siblings");
    $gender = Input::get("gender");
    $birthday = Input::get("birthdays");
    $schoolList = Input::get("school-list");
    $schoolLocation = Input::get("school-location");
    $studentAge = Input::get("student-age");
    $studentClass = Input::get("student-class");
    $stateOfOrigin = Input::get("state-of-origin");
    $chequeList = Input::get("cheque-list");



    $results = DB::table('enrollments')
             ->join('students', 'enrollments.id', '=', 'students.enrollment_id')
             ->join('parents', 'enrollments.id', '=', 'parents.enrollment_id')
             // ->join('student_pickups', 'enrollments.id', '=', 'student_pickups.enrollment_id')
             ->join('pins', 'enrollments.id', '=', 'pins.enrollment_id')
             ->join('student_proxies', 'enrollments.id', '=', 'student_proxies.enrollment_id')
             ->join('student_courses', 'enrollments.id', '=', 'student_courses.enrollment_id')
             ->join('student_feedings', 'enrollments.id', '=', 'student_feedings.enrollment_id')
             ->join('student_laptop_rentals', 'enrollments.id', '=', 'student_laptop_rentals.enrollment_id')
             ->join('student_expos', 'enrollments.id', '=', 'student_expos.enrollment_id')
             ->join('payments', 'enrollments.id', '=', 'payments.enrollment_id')
             ->join('payment_methods', 'enrollments.id', '=', 'payment_methods.enrollment_id')
             ->join('student_camp_materials', 'enrollments.id', '=', 'student_camp_materials.enrollment_id')
             ->join('attendances', 'enrollments.id', '=', 'attendances.enrollment_id')
             ->select('students.center',
                      'students.student_name',
                      'students.student_dob',
                      'students.student_sex',
                      'students.student_email',
                      'students.student_phone',
                      'students.student_home_address',
                      'students.student_city',
                      'students.student_school_name',
                      'students.student_school_city',
                      'students.student_school_state',
                      'students.student_state_of_origin',
                      'students.student_school_address',
                      'students.student_school_class',
                      'students.created_at',
                      'parents.parent_title',
                      'parents.parent_name',
                      'parents.relationship',
                      'parents.parent_email',
                      'parents.parent_phone',
                      'parents.parent_home_address',
                      'parents.parent_work_address',
                      'parents.parent_office_address',
                      'parents.created_at',
                      /*'student_pickups.child_self_pickup',
                      'student_pickups.drop_off_by_center4tech',
                      'student_pickups.parent_or_guardian_pick_up',
                      'student_pickups.proxy_pick_up',
                      'student_pickups.created_at',*/
                      'pins.pin_owner_name',
                      'pins.user_type',
                      'pins.status',
                      'pins.sign_in_pin',
                      'pins.sign_out_pin',
                      'pins.pick_up_pin',
                      'pins.drop_off_pin',
                      'pins.created_at',
                      'student_proxies.proxy_title',
                      'student_proxies.proxy_name',
                      'student_proxies.proxy_gender',
                      'student_proxies.proxy_phone',
                      'student_proxies.proxy_relationship',
                      'student_proxies.created_at',
                      'student_courses.course_name',
                      'student_courses.course_type',
                      'student_courses.course_price',
                      'student_courses.center',
                      'student_courses.computer_usage_proficiency',
                      'student_courses.created_at',
                      'student_feedings.feeding_pack_label',
                      'student_feedings.feeding_price',
                      'student_feedings.feeding_start_date',
                      'student_feedings.feeding_end_date',
                      'student_feedings.feeding_expire_notification_sms',
                      'student_feedings.feeding_expire_notification_email',
                      'student_feedings.feeding_expire_notification_parent_reminder',
                      'student_feedings.created_at',
                      'student_laptop_rentals.laptop_rental_label',
                      'student_laptop_rentals.laptop_rental_price',
                      'student_laptop_rentals.laptop_rental_start_date',
                      'student_laptop_rentals.laptop_rental_end_date',
                      'student_laptop_rentals.laptop_rental_expire_notification_sms',
                      'student_laptop_rentals.laptop_rental_expire_notification_email',
                      'student_laptop_rentals.laptop_rental_expire_notification_parent_reminder',
                      'student_laptop_rentals.is_rented',
                      'student_laptop_rentals.is_returned',
                      'student_laptop_rentals.created_at',
                      'student_expos.expo_fees',
                      'student_expos.expo_price',
                      'student_expos.created_at',
                      'payments.payment_type',
                      'payments.invoice_number',
                      'payments.item_description',
                      'payments.quantity',
                      'payments.rate',
                      'payments.discount',
                      'payments.total',
                      'payments.transaction_date',
                      'payments.verified',
                      'payments.invoice_sent',
                      'payments.invoice_sent_by_sms',
                      'payments.invoice_sent_by_email',
                      'payments.invoice_sent_date',
                      'payments.created_at',
                      'payment_methods.payment_option',
                      'payment_methods.payment_amount',
                      'payment_methods.cash_payment_confirmation',
                      'payment_methods.cash_transaction_timestamp',
                      'payment_methods.bank_pos_provider',
                      'payment_methods.bank_pos_transaction_date',
                      'payment_methods.bank_pos_transaction_time',
                      'payment_methods.bank_pos_stan',
                      'payment_methods.bank_pos_rrn',
                      'payment_methods.bank_pos_ref_no',
                      'payment_methods.bank_online_sender_account_name',
                      'payment_methods.bank_online_sender_account_number',
                      'payment_methods.bank_online_sender_bank',
                      'payment_methods.bank_online_transaction_date',
                      'payment_methods.bank_online_miu_research_bank_acc_paid_into',
                      'payment_methods.bank_online_payment_channel',
                      'payment_methods.cheque_name',
                      'payment_methods.cheque_date_to_pay_in',
                      'payment_methods.cheque_to_be_paid_in_now',
                      'payment_methods.cheque_is_post_dated',
                      'payment_methods.cheque_notification_reminder',
                      'payment_methods.bank_teller_depositor_name',
                      'payment_methods.bank_teller_transaction_date',
                      'payment_methods.bank_teller_miu_research_bank_acc_paid_into',
                      'payment_methods.is_splited_by_cash',
                      'payment_methods.split_pay_cash_amount',
                      'payment_methods.is_splited_by_pos',
                      'payment_methods.split_pay_pos_amount',
                      'payment_methods.is_splited_by_bank_transfer_online',
                      'payment_methods.split_pay_bank_transfer_pc_mobile_amount',
                      'payment_methods.is_splited_by_teller',
                      'payment_methods.split_pay_deposit_teller_amount',
                      'payment_methods.is_splited_by_cheque',
                      'payment_methods.split_pay_cheque_amount',
                      'payment_methods.is_parted_by_cash',
                      'payment_methods.is_parted_by_pos',
                      'payment_methods.is_parted_by_bank_transfer',
                      'payment_methods.is_parted_by_teller',
                      'payment_methods.is_parted_by_cheque',
                      'payment_methods.advance_payment_amount',
                      'payment_methods.balance_payment_outstanding',
                      'payment_methods.balance_payment_due_date',
                      'payment_methods.balance_payment_status',
                      'payment_methods.pdf_generated',
                      'payment_methods.receipt_sent',
                      'payment_methods.receipt_sent_by_sms',
                      'payment_methods.receipt_sent_by_email',
                      'payment_methods.receipt_sent_by_pdf',
                      'payment_methods.receipt_sent_date',
                      'payment_methods.status',
                      'payment_methods.created_at',
                      'student_camp_materials.course_material_given',
                      'student_camp_materials.electronic_kit_given',
                      'student_camp_materials.enrollment_completed',
                      'student_camp_materials.enrollment_not_completed',
                      'student_camp_materials.created_at',
                      'attendances.present',
                      'attendances.absent',
                      'attendances.sign_in',
                      'attendances.sign_out',
                      'attendances.operation',
                      'attendances.extra',
                      'attendances.created_at',
                     )
            // ->orWhere('students.center','LIKE','%'.$center.'%')
             ->orWhere('students.center',$center)
             ->orWhere('student_courses.course_name',$course)
             ->orWhere('parents.parent_phone')
             ->orWhere('parents.parent_email')
             ->orWhere('parents.parent_office_address')
             ->orWhere('student_courses.course_name',$course)
             ->get();


    /*if ( isset($center) ) {

        $results = Student::where("center",$center)->get();
    }

    if ( isset($course) ) {

        $results = Studentcourse::where("course_name",$course)->get();
    }*/

    return $results;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's certainly a long query and I'm sure there is some optimisation to be made - both code and query.

You need to be a little more detailed on what kind of errors you are getting and how we can help, example expected results etc. However, here's a few things I've quickly spotted -

1. That controller is never going to succeed, the query is flawed.
2. Most of those variables seem to be going unused. You'd be better off calling them directly from the request and saving a few lines of code.
3. Some of your where's don't even have a condition - that'll cause a failure.

```
->orWhere('parents.parent_phone')
->orWhere('parents.parent_email')
->orWhere('parents.parent_office_address')
```

4. Probably worth grouping your queries a little more. E.g.

```php
->where(function ($builder) {
    $builder
        ->where('students.center', request()->center)
        ->orWhere('student_courses.course_name', $course = request()->course)
        ->orWhere('student_courses.course_name', $course);
})
->get();
```

Overall I'd really recommend reviewing all of your code and tidying it up where possible.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @Chris the "where's don't even have a condition" that is because the select options has other options below.

Comment: `->where(function ($builder) {
    $builder
        ->where('students.center', request()->center)
        ->orWhere('student_courses.course_name', $course = request()->course)
        ->orWhere('student_courses.course_name', $course);
})
->get();` Can i perform if else conditions based on the request input values?

Comment: I see, are you just checking the values aren't null? You can group queries in where blocks to achieve this kind of thing